# Suppressing page number in list of abbreviations in LaTeX report

Tags: page-numbering, glossaries, two-column, acronyms

I have a LaTeX report as follows in a file called `Main.tex`:

```
documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\input{Glossary}

\input{ChapterX}
\input{ChapterY}
\input{ChapterZ}

\end{document}
```

And I'm trying to create a list of abbreviations from the file `Glossary.tex` which is imported into `Main.tex`.

`Glossary.tex` is simply:

```
\chapter*{List of abbreviations}
\newacronym{jdbc}{JDBC}{Java database connectivity}
\newacronym{jsp}{JSP}{Java server pages}
\newacronym{sql}{SQL}{Structured query language}
\printglossaries
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of abbreviations}
```

After doing this I am supposed to run this instruction at the Windows command line in the same folder as the LaTeX files:

```
makeglossaries main.tex
```

But what I do find is that the abbreviations display with page numbers like this;

```
JDBC Java database connectivity. 14
```

So how can I surppress the page numbers and is it possible to use two columns for the abbreviations?

Comment: Don't use the file extension when you run `makeglossaries`. It should have detected the `.tex` extension and given you an error message. Just run `makeglossaries main`

Comment: If @NicolaTalbot doesn't nobody does, but I suspect you failed to ping due to the spurious space.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Good Glossaries for Dummies instructions. The list of abbreviations is now in my report but do you know how how can I suppress the page numbers and is it possible to use two columns for the abbreviations?

Comment: I'd actually pinged her for you but I don't expect it hurts to ping twice ;).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The page number list can be suppressed using the `nonumberlist` package option.

```
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
```

For two columns, try one of the [`mcol` glossary styles](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:mcolstyles). For example:

```
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\setglossarystyle{mcolindex}
```